# Given two arrays, `a` and `b`, how to find efficiently all combinations of elements in `b` that have equal value in `a`?

Tags: numpy, pytorch

Given two arrays, `a` and `b`, how to find efficiently all combinations of elements in `b` that have equal value in `a`?

here is an example:

Given

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
b = [1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 3, 7, 22, 10]
```

how would you calculate

```
c = [[1, 2],
     [1, 4],
     [2, 4],
     [5, 9],
     [3, 7],
     [3, 22],
     [3, 10],
     [7, 22],
     [7, 10],
     [22, 10]]
```

?

`a` can be assumed to be sorted.

I can do this with loops, a la:

```py
import torch

a = torch.tensor([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])
b = torch.tensor([1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 3, 7, 22, 10])

jumps = torch.cat((torch.tensor([0]),
                   torch.where(a.diff() > 0)[0] + 1,
                   torch.tensor([len(a)])))
cs = []
for i in range(len(jumps) - 1):
    cs.append(torch.combinations(b[jumps[i]:jumps[i + 1]]))
c = torch.cat(cs)
```

Is there any efficient way to avoid the loop? The solution should work for CPU and CUDA.
Also, the solution should have runtime O(*m* * *m*), where *m* is the largest number of equal elements in `a` and not O(*n* * *n*) where *n* is the length of of `a`.

I prefer solutions for pytorch, but I am curious for solution for numpy as well.

Answer (score -1):

I think the overhead of using torch is only justified for bigger datasets, as there is basically no computational difficulty in the function, imho you can achieve same results with:

```
from collections import Counter

def find_combinations1(a, b):
    count_a = Counter(a)
    combinations = []
    for x in set(b):
        if count_a[x] == b.count(x):
            combinations.append(x)
    return combinations
```

or even a simpler:

```
def find_combinations2(a, b):
    return list(set(a) & set(b))
```

With `pytorch` I assume the most simple approach is:

```
import torch
def find_combinations3(a, b):
    a = torch.tensor(a)
    b = torch.tensor(b)
    eq = torch.eq(a, b.view(-1, 1))
    indices = torch.nonzero(eq)
    return indices[:, 1]
```

This option has of course a time complexity of O(n*m) where n is the size of a and m is the size of b, and O(n+m) is the memory for the tensors.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, it doesn't answer the question asked. Your code does not return `c`. I agree that PyTorch is only for big datasets, I just gave a small example.